# Is there always a partition into distinct divisors of an abundant number involving the largest nontrivial divisor?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

With the obvious exception of weird numbers like $70$, for which such partitions are not possible at all.

For example, with $12$, we have $6 + 4 + 2 = 12$.

With a larger abundant number like $60$ there of course are partitions that don't use the largest nontrivial divisor, like $20 + 15 + 10 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 60$, but there is also at least one that does: $30 + 20 + 10$.

Does there exist an abundant number, but not weird, which can be partitioned into a selection of its distinct divisors, but *none* of which use the largest nontrivial divisor?

The answer to this question seems like it should obviously be "No, of course not." But how to prove it?

I've mostly only looked at even abundant numbers, but I've also looked at $945$. But of course there could exist some ridiculously large number meeting this criterion.

Comment: Nice question! (+1)

Comment: There is no need to look at odd ones, they present no threat when it comes to your question.

Comment: If my calculations are right.

Comment: If we can trust the OEIS-sequence with the priimitive pseudoperfect numbers, no primitive pseudoperfect number below $580\ 000$ (and of course no multiple of any of those primitive pseudoperfect numbers) is a counter-example.

Comment: I have passed the $1\ 100\ 000$-mark approving the result given in the answer.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Show us why there cannot be an odd counterexample!

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid I can't provide a full answer, but here's some results that I've managed to come up with.

Lets first agree on some terminology.

A positive integer is called *perfect* if it equals the sum of its proper divisors.
   A positive integer is called *deficient* if it exceeds the sum of its proper divisors.
   A positive integer is called *abundant* if it is exceeded by the sum of its proper divisors.
   A positive integer is called *pseudoperfect* if it equals the sum of a subset of its proper divisors.

Clearly, every perfect number is also pseudoperfect, and no deficient number is pseudoperfect.

A positive integer that is abundant, but not pseudoperfect is called *weird*.

So far, this is standard terminology; lets introduce a further concept:

A positive integer is called *strongly pseudoperfect* if it equals the sum of a subset of its proper divisors containing the largest proper divisor.

It is clear that perfect numbers are strongly pseudoperfect and that strongly pseudoperfect numbers are pseudoperfect.

Finally, we call an abundant number *semi-weird* if it is neither weird nor strongly pseudoperfect.

Then your question can be re-stated as: **Do semi-weird numbers exist?**

With the use of a computer, I have found that no semi-weird numbers less than one million exist.

To ease computation, we make use of the following lemmas:

(1) If $n$ is strongly pseudoperfect, then every multiple of $n$ is as well.
(2) If $n=2^m\cdot p$ for a positive integer $m$ and a prime $p<2^{m+1}$, then $n$ is strongly pseudoperfect.

Using these two facts, if $s$ is the smallest semi-weird number, then the following hold.

- $s$ is abundant.
- $s$ is not weird.
- All divisors of $s$ are either deficient or weird.
- $s$ is not of the form $2^m\cdot p$ for a prime $p<2^{m+1}$.

If you reduce the numbers below one million to just the candidates for minimal semi-weirdness that satisfy these four conditions, you get a much smaller list of 1795 numbers (starting at $350$ and ending with $999999$). It is then easy to check that all of these are in fact strongly pseudoperfect.

Therefore, if semi-weird numbers exist at all, they must be larger than a million.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed a small logical flaw in my reasoning; however, the result does not change because of that.  
I'm editing the answer accordingly.

Comment: A more thorough look at the matter yields a fifth necessary condition for the smallest semi-weird number $s$: If $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $s$, then $s/p$ is either weird or coprime to $p$.  
This allows to further filter the candidates and search in a much wider range. In this way I could show that no semi-weird number exists among the positive integers up to 50 million.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't accept this answer at this point but I hope you appreciate the bounty points as a small token of my appreciation for your insights.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks, thanks a whole lot for the bounty; I wish I could have provided a little more insight into the interesting problem you came up with. In this case, I don't even have a clear "gut feeling" about whether or not numbers as yours exist - in fact; I still wouldn't be surprised too much if they do (even though empirical eveidence suggests the opposite). Is there a specific context in which this problem arises?

Comment: @jpvee Is "semi-weird" your invention ? And how sure can we be with the $50$-million bound ? My intuition : Although $50$ millions is not a very large bound in usual number-theory-problems, I think that there are no numbers with the desired property. And although I have no clue how a proof could look, I think there is a relatively easy proof that there are none.

Comment: @Peter: Sure, the term "semi-weird" is something I made up (as opposed to "weird" which is an established term); perhaps "weirder" would have been more suitable. Regarding the question on how sure that bound is: Very good question; I wrote a program (using GAP) to check all numbers up to $50000000$, but of course it's quite possible that it has bugs left in it. Maybe someone else can verify it (ideally with a different program). I am, however, pretty positive that five necessary conditions I gave for a smallest semi-weird number (and which are the basis for my program) are correct.

Comment: "Is there a specific context in which this problem arises?" I think it was only because I was thinking about whether it's best to sort the divisors in ascending or descending order.